# Changing color of an SVG.Use element in js

Tags: image, svg, colors, svg.js

I am using the library [SVG.js](https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/) and here's a piece of my code

```
var main_field = SVG('field');
var rn = main_field.defs().image('rn.png',70,70);
var a = main_field.use(rn).move(70,70);
```

Now I'd like to manipulate the colors of the image, but

```
a.fill({color: '#f06', opacity: 0.6 });
a.stroke({ color: '#f06', opacity: 1, width: 5 });
```

both do nothing. The only attribute I can change seems to be the opacity

```
a.opacity(0.2);
```

Is there a way to change the color of the image, or I must overlay an uniform image filled with the color to obtain the effect?

Comment: `fill` and `stroke` properties have no effect for `<image>` elements (as that would be properties its content), but `opacity` has (it just describes how to blend the image with its background). What is it exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: As ccprog said, changing the color of the image (`rn.png`) in that manner is not possible. You could possibly do it with filters, depending on the desired result. Can you provide more detail on what the end result should be?

Comment: @Ted  I'm trying to overlay a uniform color onto the image (like fill does with rect,etc.) or produce a border to the image (like stroke does)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the stroke or fill of an image. However, you can change fill and stroke of a rectangle. You can use that by creating a symbol which contains the image and a rectangle on top of it. When you apply a fill or stroke to the `<use>` element, it will look like the image has the fill / stroke:

svg.js v3.0 code:

```
const width = window.innerWidth
const height = window.innerHeight

const canvas = SVG()
  .addTo('body')
  .size(width, height)

const sym = canvas.symbol()
const image = sym.image('https://images.gutefrage.net/media/fragen/bilder/bild-spiegeln-ohne-das-es-einen-hintergrund-bekommt/0_original.jpg?v=1354472980000', (event, a) => {
  const {width, height} = event.target
  sym.rect(width, height)
})

canvas.use(sym)
  .fill({color: 'red', opacity: 0.5})
  .stroke({color: 'black', width: 2})
```

svg.js v2.x code:

```
const width = window.innerWidth
const height = window.innerHeight

const canvas = SVG('field')

const sym = canvas.symbol()
const image = sym.image('https://images.gutefrage.net/media/fragen/bilder/bild-spiegeln-ohne-das-es-einen-hintergrund-bekommt/0_original.jpg?v=1354472980000').loaded((data) => {
  const {width, height} = data
  sym.rect(width, height)
})

canvas.use(sym)
  .fill({color: 'red', opacity: 0.5})
  .stroke({color: 'black', width: 2})
```